# Matrix of a Vector as a Column of the Matrix of a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am working through Axler's **Linear Algebra Done Right (Third Edition)** and I ran into an issue with his **Theorem 3.64** which I will detail below.

The issue I have with this theorem could be one of three things: Axler uses dubious notation, the theorem is wrong, or I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the content. Obviously we all know which one is more likely, so my goal is to fix any conceptual issues that I may have before moving forward too far. This chapter is about linear maps (linear transformations) and this section is specifically about invertible linear maps and isomorphic vector spaces. In this theorem, Axler is prepping to put together the ideas of the *matrix of a linear map*, the *matrix of a vector*, and *matrix multiplication* so he can prove that "linear maps act like matrix multiplication."

Before I present the theorem, here's some notation that he uses which may or may not be standard, I don't know. The set of linear maps from vector space $V$ to vector space $W$ is denoted $L(V,W)$. The invertible linear map that takes a linear map to its $m \times n$ matrix is denoted $M$ and so the matrix of a linear map, say $T \in L(V,W)$, is $M(T)$. In the theorem, Axler clarifies other potentially unfamiliar notation. Okay here's the theorem with its short, elaborating preamble.

"Recall that if A is an $m \times n$ matrix, then $A_{.,k}$ denotes the $k^{th}$ column of A, thought of as an $m \times 1$ matrix. In the next result, $M(v_k)$ is computed with respect to the basis $w_1,...,w_n$ of $W$.

***3.64*** $M(T)_{.,k}=M(v_k)$.

Suppose $T \in L(V,W)$ and $v_1,...v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1,...,w_n$ is a basis of $W$. Let $1 \le k \le n$. Then the $k^{th}$ column of $M(T)$, which is denoted by $M(T)_{.,k}$, equals $M(v_k)$.

***Proof*** $\;$ The desired result follows immediately from the definitions of $M(T)$ and $M(v_k)$."

To put it simply, I feel as though the statement should be that $M(T)_{.,k}=M(Tv_k)$. The definition of $M(T)$ states that each column of the matrix contains the constants required to write $Tv_k$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors in $W$. This can always be done since $range\ T \subseteq W$. Also, the definition of the matrix of a vector, $M(v)$, is the $n \times 1$ matrix that contains the coefficients required to write $v \in V$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors of $V$ (I'm assuming, here, that $dim\ V=n$).

From Axler's notation, I assume that $v_k$ is one of the $n$ basis vectors. Immediately Axler states that $M(v_k)$ is computed using the basis of the codomain which, from the definition of the matrix of a vector, implies that $v_k$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors of $W$. Only, this can't be true all the time: for example
consider $T \in L(\mathbb{R^3}, \mathbb{R^2})$. You surely cannot write an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R^3}$ as a linear combination of some basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$, right? I feel as though, using my statement, Axler's "proof" works rather well, but still I am not confident. Finally, Axler uses this result in his next theorem where he declares that each $M(Tv_k)=M(T)_{.,k}$, just like my statement.

Where are my wires crossed? Thank you very much for reading and considering!

Comment: He’s wrong. Let’s just say it in words. The $k$th column of $M(T)$ is the coordinate vector (in terms of the $w$ basis) of $Tv_k$.

Comment: Ah, of course, saying it in words; it's nice to know you can do that sometimes! Thank you for your answer it helped a ton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your question deals with a typo in the third edition of my book *Linear Algebra Done Right*. Specifically, $M(v_k)$ in lines 2, 4, 7, and 9 on page 85 should be $M(Tv_k)$. My apologies for this typo. It has already been corrected in the forthcoming fourth edition of the book, to be published in November 2023 or December 2023.

The fourth edition will be an Open Access book, meaning that the electronic version will be legally free on the book's website [linear.axler.net](https://linear.axler.net). Chapters 5 and 7 of the fourth edition are already freely available on that website.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for responding and congrats on the new edition, I look forward to it!